# Determine Big-oh notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

In my preparations for the Algorithms exam I tried to solve the following Big-Oh questions, so can you check them for me

```
for(i=1; i<n; i++){ 
 i=i*3;
 for(j=15; j>=6; j--){
  System.out.print(i*j);
 }
}
```

Answer:O(lg<sub>3</sub>n)

```
for(j=1; j<n; j++){
 System.out.print(j*2);
 }
for(k=n;k>=1; k=k/2) {
System.out.print(k);
}
```

Answer: O(n)

```
for(i=1; i<n; i++){
 i=i+5;
 for(j=m; j>=0; j--){
  System.out.print(i*j);
  } }
```

Answer: O(mn)

```
for(i=1; i<n; i++){ 
for(j=i; j<=i+7; j++){
 System.out.print(i*j);
 } }
```

Answer: Actually this one was hard but I think it's O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

In the last case, `j<=i+7` is `j<i+8`, so you you have `O(8*N)` (where `N` is your `n`), that is `O(N)` (O-notation is unaware of const values).

Comment: What about the rest are my answers right?
and for the last one it is not always moving 8 times n if n is 2 for example it is only iterating 10 times
isn't it 8+N

Comment: oh, sorry, I've understood the question was only on the last one!! :-)

Comment: @Mira keep in mind that `O(N)` notation gives you an idea of the complexity for any generic `N`, while you are evaluating a very specific case by saying *if N is 2*. Moreover, if `n` is 2, who cares about the performance issue? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are correct, *typically* if you have nested for loops your runtime will always be O(n^2).

Also, if it is a single for loop, it will be O(n) entirely dependent on the size, however, if in the second for loop, if you ran it to a variable m times, your notation would be O(m) because m>n and since all constants are dropped, you would take the larger option.

Edit: You showed one of the occasions when a nested **wouldn't** be n^2, guess I didn't see that one.